# Segment ignored in effective address with nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to write a simple bootloader in x86 assembly using nasm. At several places in the code, I have to use an effective address of the form `[es:di]`. The code compiles without error, but at run time, the segment is ignored. For instance, for

```
mov ax, 0x07C0
mov es, ax
mov di, 0x10
lea eax, [es:di]
```

Right after the `lea`, the registers look like :

```
EAX=00000010 
EDI=00000010
ES =07c0 00007c00 0000ffff 00009300
```

But EAX should have been `7C10`. The problem occurs at any point of the program (including when nothing has been done before), and the program runs in real mode.

My question is: is this normal? Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Intel's manual may not be super clear on this. Or it may not be obvious where to look, at least. But if you read section 7.3.16.1 (`Address Computation Instruction`), it says:

> The `LEA` (load effective address) instruction computes the effective address in memory (**offset within a segment**)
>   of a source operand and places it in a general-purpose register.

So, yes, I'd say that your result is the expected one.